# TEM Propagation in Infinite Ferrit Medium

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave, propagation

I have realised a question on Collin's Foundations of Microwave Engineering book which is related to TEM propagation in infinite ferrit medium.

I could not find a way to establish to relate positive and negative admittances with propagation direction. 
[image: question]

This is a [link](http://www.imgim.com/9990incia3482531.png) for question.

Comment: Hi! You forgot to actually ask a precise question, and this is a Question & Answer site. Where are you stuck, what have you tried, what do you (not) understand about this question?

Comment: I have mentioned the point. Thank you.

Comment: OK, you've added what you've not been able to do. But we can't tell *why* you've not been able too, making it very hard to help you. Please add your calculations so far.

Comment: Thank you. I just need to learn a method to start.

Comment: The *Hint:* gives you one...